# C# How to sort a jagged array by index

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I want to sort a jagged array by following condition:

```
if array[i][0] != array[j][0], compare by array[i][0] - array[j][0]
if array[i][0] != array[j][0], compare by i - j
i, j is index of array
```

Here is an example:

```
int[][] array = new int[3][]
{
    new int[2] {1, 2},
    new int[2] {0, 1},
    new int[2] {1, 1}
};
```

sorted result

```
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]]
```

i try to use IComparer but don't know how to implement or any other method to solve this problem.

Thanks

=====================================================================

Problem solved but got different result between Array.Sort() and Linq.

```
public void TestSort()
{
    int[][] array = new int[6][]
    {
        new int[4]{2,6,9,4},
        new int[4]{4,8,7,5},
        new int[4]{4,6,7,6},
        new int[4]{2,3,3,7},
        new int[4]{9,3,6,8},
        new int[4]{2,8,8,4}
    };

    // Use Array.Sort()
    JaggedArrayComparer cp = new JaggedArrayComparer();
    cp.array = array;
    Array.Sort(array, cp);
    Console.WriteLine("Sort by Array.Sort() =================");
    foreach (var e in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e[0]} {e[1]} {e[2]} {e[3]}");
    }

    // Use Linq
    // array = array.OrderBy(a => a[0]).ThenBy(a => Array.IndexOf(array, a)).ToArray();
    // Console.WriteLine("Sort by Linq =================");
    // foreach (var e in array)
    // {
    //     Console.WriteLine($"{e[0]} {e[1]} {e[2]} {e[3]}");
    // }
}

class JaggedArrayComparer : IComparer
{
    public int[][] array;
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int[] xArray = (int[])x;
        int[] yArray = (int[])y;

        if (xArray[0] != yArray[0])
        {
            return xArray[0] - yArray[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return Array.IndexOf(array, xArray) - Array.IndexOf(array, yArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Expect output is same as Linq Output. What is the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Sort method and provide it with a comparer function as you like

something like this

```
Comparison<int[]> MyCoolComparison(List<int[]> intsList)
{
    return (x, y) => (x[0] != y[0])
        ? x[0].CompareTo(y[0]
        : intsList.IndexOf(x) - intsList.IndexOf(y);
}
```

and then the usage is simple:

```
array.Sort(MyCoolComparison(array));
```

you can of course create a comparison class implementing the IComparer interface
and in the compare method implement the same logic

and use it like this:

```
class MyComparerClass: IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // logic
    }
}
Array.Sort(array, new MyComparerClass());
```

Comment: Thanks @Dor Lugasi-Gal. IndexOf block me before. Now this problem has been solved.  But a new issue raise when i test. Different behavior bewteen Array.Sort() and Linq, seems Linq can get the correct answer. I will write test code under this question. Great thanks if you can help explain the reason.

Comment: Side note: better use `x[0].CompareTo(y[0])` instead of `x[0] - y[0]`, since `x[0] - y[0]` can result as *integer overflow*, e.g. when `x[0] = 1_000_000_000` and `y[0] = -2_000_000_000`: `x[0] - y[0] == 3_000_000_000 > int.MaxValue`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko good suggestion, i modified it